# How to change query of firestore when click on a button and show data to recyclerview android

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am creating an app where I need to show different data on different item click of the navigation drawer
I want to **change** **query** when I click on the navigation drawer menu and show the data on the same fragment.

**This code is working fine, I want to know how to change firestore query to show the different data on the same fragment**

I try to pass the data from mainActivity but app crashing I try simple passing the query by creating an object of LatestFragment class in the main activity.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    //adding the toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    LatestFragment latestFragment = new LatestFragment(); // this should be in FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()
    TrendingFragment trendingFragment = new TrendingFragment(); // this should be in FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()
    DailyQuizFragment dailyQuizFragment = new DailyQuizFragment(); // this should be in FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()
    YojanaFragment yojanaFragment = new YojanaFragment(); // this should be in FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()

    //tablayout setup with viewPager
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //setting viewPager Adapter
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),0);

    //adding fragment to viewPager Adapter start
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(latestFragment,"latest"); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(trendingFragment,"trending"); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(dailyQuizFragment,"daily quiz"); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(yojanaFragment,"yojana"); // this line can cause crashes
    //adding fragment to viewPager Adapter end

    //adding viewPager Adapter
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    //adding icon to tab layout start
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_icon_black);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_trending_icon_black);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_snooze_icon_black);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_book_icon_black);
    //adding icon to tab layout start

    //navigation drawer start
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.openNavDrawer,
            R.string.closeNavDrawer
    );

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    //navigation drawer end

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           update();

        }
    });
}

//navigation drawer method start
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}//navigation drawer method end

public void update(){
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    if (tabLayout.getTabCount()>2) {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(3);
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(2);
    }
}


}
```

**LatestFragment**

```
public class LatestFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirestoreAdapter firestorePagingAdapter;

    public LatestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.latest_recView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        fetch();

        return view;
    }

    public void fetch() {
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        //Query
        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("History");

        //Pagination
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(3)
                .build();

        //RecyclerOption
        FirestorePagingOptions<AdapterData> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<AdapterData>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
                .setQuery(query, config, AdapterData.class)
                .build();

        firestorePagingAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firestorePagingAdapter);
    }

}
```

**FirestoreAdapter**

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<AdapterData, FirestoreAdapter.ProductsViewHolder> {


public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<AdapterData> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final AdapterData model) {
    Log.d("data",model.getTitle());

    holder.recView_title.setText(model.getTitle());
    holder.recView_content.setText(model.getContent());

    holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FullSrcreenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",model.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra("content",model.getContent());
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ProductsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_layout, parent,false);
    return new ProductsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
    super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);
    switch (state) {
        case LOADING_MORE:
            Log.d("PAGING_LOG","Loading Next Page");
            break;
        case LOADING_INITIAL:
            Log.d("PAGING_LOG","Loading Initial Data");
            break;
        case FINISHED:
            Log.d("PAGING_LOG","All Data Loaded");
            break;
        case ERROR:
            Log.d("PAGING_LOG","ERROR Loading Data");
            break;
        case LOADED:
            Log.d("PAGING_LOG","Total Item Loaded : " + getItemCount());

            break;
    }
}

//View Holder
public class ProductsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView recView_title, recView_content;
    View view;

    public ProductsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        recView_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
        view = itemView;
    }
}
}
```

**AdapterData**

```
public class AdapterData {

    private String title;
    private String content;

    public AdapterData() {}

    public AdapterData(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo this code is working fine, I want to know how to change firestore query to show the different data on the same fragment

Comment: What is the new query that you want to perform?

Comment: @AlexMamo Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Enviormnet"); or  Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("History").orderBy("title");

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: @AlexMamo when I run the app it works fine but I don't know how to change the query and show data to the fragment recycler View, I want to change the query on click event like by pressing an item from the drawer menu item.